# Error: undefined method `avatar?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am receiving the following errors in my rails app.

### Error:

```
NoMethodError in Statuses#index
```

Showing C:/Users/Arvind/project/book/app/views/statuses/index.html.erb where line #12 raised:

undefined method `avatar?' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: C:/Users/Arvind/project/book Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/helpers/applicationhelper.rb:28:in avatar_profile_link' app/views/statuses/index.html.erb:12:inblock in _app_views_statuses_index_html_erb__844883668_70166988' app/views/statuses/index.html.erb:9:in _app_views_statuses_index_html_erb___844883668_70166988' app/controllers/statuses_controller.rb:13:inindex'

---

My user.rb

---

```
 attr_accessible  :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :profile_name, :full_name, :avatar
```

has_attached_file :avatar, style: { large: "800x800>", medium: "300x200>", small: "260x180>", thumb: "80x80#" }

```
  def self.get_gravatars
     all.each do |user|
       if !user.avatar?
       user.avatar = URI.parse(user.gravatar_url)
            user.save
                print "."
              end
         end
     end
```

---

My application_helper.rb

```
def avatar_profile_link(user, image_options={}, html_options={})
```

avatar_url = user.avatar? ? user.avatar.url(:thumb) : nil

```
link_to(image_tag(avatar_url, image_options),   profile_path(user.profile_name), html_options)
```

end

---

My lib/task/gravatars,rake

---

```
desc "Import avatars from user's gravatar url"
   task :import_avatars => :environment do
      puts "Importing avatars from gravatar"
         User.get_gravatars
            puts "Avatars updated."
      end
```

---

I updated My avatar to gravatar

---

```
$rake import avatar
```

Importing avatar to gravatar

.....Avatar updated.

---

My git repository is at: [https://github.com/sarahgupta022/book.git](https://github.com/sarahgupta022/book)

---

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in /app/helpers/application_helper.rb in avatar_profile_link method, you have to check if user is nil. Replace with this code:

```
def avatar_profile_link(user, image_options={}, html_options={})
  avatar_url = nil
  unless user.nil?
    avatar_url = user.avatar? ? user.avatar.url(:thumb) : nil
    link_to(image_tag(avatar_url, image_options), profile_path(user.profile_name), html_options)
  end
end
```

Comment: it's giving me error: undefined method `user?' for #<#<Class:0x52cda90>:0x52d6e68> in same line. but when i put this code  without question mark "if user" then it's give me undefined method `profile_name' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: I try to put "try" in my code: def avatar_profile_link(user, image_options={}, html_options={})
     avatar_url = user.try(:avatar?) ? user.avatar.url(:thumb) : nil
     link_to(image_tag(avatar_url, image_options), profile_path(user.try(:profile_name)), html_options)                            end                                                                                                        but no user same error is coming.

Comment: the object status doesn´t return the value of user. Maybe you need to get user with current_user method. user = current_user. I don't how works your status object.

Comment: Again the same  Error: undefined method `avatar?' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: This is my status.rb:-                         class Status< ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible  :context, :document_attributes, :avatar
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :document
 
 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :document
 
 validates :context, presence: true,
                     length: { minimum: 2}
  
  validates :user_id, presence: true  
  
  
                 
end

Comment: great!!!! when now the error is "undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass" when i remove <%= status.user.full_name %> from my index.html.erb(statuses). status page is looking good but missing user name.

Comment: I edited my code as: def avatar_profile_link(user, image_options={}, html_options={})                                                                                                                                                                                                
    avatar_url = nil
    if user.nil?
     avatar_url = current_user.avatar? ? current_user.avatar.url(:thumb) : nil
     link_to(image_tag(avatar_url, image_options), profile_path(current_user.profile_name), html_options)
     end
  end

Comment: now it's working when i put <%= status.try(:user).try(:full_name) %>. but problem is that if i am putting current_user.avatar and if someone else is my friend then also it's shows my profile not my friend profile. in this case i am not able to see my friends status. :( overall problem not solve.

Comment: now i updated my code:def avatar_profile_link(user, image_options={}, html_options={})
    avatar_url = nil
    if user
     avatar_url = user.avatar? ? user.avatar.url(:thumb) : nil
     link_to(image_tag(avatar_url, image_options), profile_path(user.profile_name), html_options)
     end
  end. and now i can make friendship with my friends also but now problem is that edit and delete btn is not coming in status, so i'm not able to delete my status. :( and in my friends status page avatar icon is not showing.

Comment: now it's working except avatar and status edit and delete btn., avatar is not being upload in statuses and delete btn is not display with status.

Comment: Nice your moving foward with your code. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank You!!!!  but now my avatar is not uploading in statuses page.  I get error in my rails server : Unpermitted parameters: first_name, last_name, avatar.

Answer (score 1):

The error message states:

```
undefined method `avatar?' for nil:NilClass
```

The `avatar_profile_link` helper method accepts a `user` argument. The value for `user` is `nil` at the point where the error occurs.

Looking at your git repo, the offending section is most likely here:

```
<% @statuses.each do |status| %>
<% if can_display_status?(status) %>
     <div class="status media">
        <%= avatar_profile_link status.user, {}, class: 'pull-left' %>
```

At least one `status` has a user of `nil`. That's about as far as we can see based on what you shared so for.

Comment: Really i'm not able to help my self, were exactly i went wrong :(

Comment: You could start by trying to figure out why the `status` doesn't have an associated user. How is the status created?